# Specify type names in a SOAP response in .net

Tags: .net, soap

I'm new to .net and trying to build the server side of a SOAP web service.  The client is already implemented by someone else and I'm not allowed to make changes, so I have to conform to the client's expectations.

So far I've figured out how to change the SOAPAction and rename the types used for inputs into the web methods, using attributes for both.  But the same techniques seem to fail for the response value.

For one particular web method, the client expects:

`...

<method_response>

<message_response/>

<message_response/>

</method_response>

...`

So I try this:

```
[WebMethod]
[SoapDocumentMethod(ResponseElementName = "method_response")]
public MessageResponse[] method(String input) {
    ...

[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlType(TypeName = "message_response")]
public class MessageResponse {
    ....
```

But the web service returns

`<method_response>

<methodResult>

<message_response/>

<message_response/>

</methodResult>

</method_response>`

Any idea how I can force the web server to not return the `<methodResult>` tags?

Comment: You should not be using ASMX for new development. All new development should be using WCF.